# Long nested IF statement creates runtime error 1004 in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, nested-if

I have a formula that works perfectly well in a spreadsheet, but when I try to automate the creation of the formula using VBA, I get the 1004 run time error.

I have a 3 stage process, each with a start and finish date (so 6 separate date columns). This formula looks at the series dates and calculates the time lost between each stage using the NETWORKDAYS function.

I thought the simple way to overcome this problem was to record a macro of me pasting this formula into a cell, which would generate the required VBA code that I could then adapt, but even using this method causes the 1004 error.

I'm wondering whether it's the length of the formula that's the problem?  I've tried replacing the double quotation marks with `& Chr(34) & Chr(34) &` and I've tried assigning the formula to a variable. I can get it to work if I add it as text using .value instead of .formulaR1C1, or if I add an apostrophe to the start of the formula string. It appears to be the fact that its a formula that causes the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The formula from the cell in the spreadsheet:

```
=IF(AND(I2="",J2="",K2="",L2=""),"",IF(AND(G2="",H2="",K2="",L2=""),"",IF(AND(G2="",H2="",I2="",J2=""),"",IF(AND(H2<>"",I2<>"",J2<>"",K2<>""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2+NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2<1,"",NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2+NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2),IF(AND(H2<>"",I2<>""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2<1,"",NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2),IF(AND(H2<>"",K2<>""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(H2,K2)-2<1,"",NETWORKDAYS(H2,K2)-2),IF(AND(J2<>"",K2<>""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2<1,"",NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2),"")))))))
```

The code that the macro records when I enter the formula into the cell:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(RC[-10]="""",RC[-9]="""",RC[-8]="""",RC[-7]=""""),"""",IF(AND(RC[-12]="""",RC[-11]="""",RC[-8]="""",RC[-7]=""""),"""",IF(AND(RC[-12]="""",RC[-11]="""",RC[-10]="""",RC[-9]=""""),"""",IF(AND(RC[-11]<>"""",RC[-10]<>"""",RC[-9]<>"""",RC[-8]<>""""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-11],RC[-10])-2+NETWORKDAYS(RC[-9],RC[-8])-2<1,"""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-11],RC[-10])-2+NETWORKDAYS(RC[" & _
        "8])-2),IF(AND(RC[-11]<>"""",RC[-10]<>""""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-11],RC[-10])-2<1,"""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-11],RC[-10])-2),IF(AND(RC[-11]<>"""",RC[-8]<>""""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-11],RC[-8])-2<1,"""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-11],RC[-8])-2),IF(AND(RC[-9]<>"""",RC[-8]<>""""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-9],RC[-8])-2<1,"""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-9],RC[-8])-2),"""")))))))"
```

Comment: Please revise with code formatting...

Comment: Also, indicate in which cell you're trying to paste this formula.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to sort the formatting (it's my first post), but thanks to whoever did fix it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which cell the formula goes into, it's the process of doing it by VBA that is the problem.  I'm intending to place the formula in a column with 1,000s of rows of data.

Comment: Oh but it does matter because of the offsets, a formula could refer to invalid ranges,etc. Fwiw, I enter the formula and it errors in any cell so the issue would seem to be with the formyla string itself. Anyways, it looks like you've got a solution already, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub EvilFormula()
    Dim st As String, DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    st = "=IF(AND(I2=~,J2=~,K2=~,L2=~),~,IF(AND(G2=~,H2=~,K2=~,L2=~),~,IF(AND(G2=~,H2=~,I2=~,J2=~),~,IF(AND(H2<>~,I2<>~,J2<>~,K2<>~),IF(NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2+NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2<1,~,NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2+NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2),IF(AND(H2<>~,I2<>~),IF(NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2<1,~,NETWORKDAYS(H2,I2)-2),IF(AND(H2<>~,K2<>~),IF(NETWORKDAYS(H2,K2)-2<1,~,NETWORKDAYS(H2,K2)-2),IF(AND(J2<>~,K2<>~),IF(NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2<1,~,NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2)-2),~)))))))"
    st = Replace(st, "~", DQ)
    ActiveCell.Formula = st
End Sub
```

Here we first construct a *String* that represents the formula, but uses *tildas* in place of **pairs** of double-quotes.  We replace the tildas and deposit the formula.
*I use this to avoid migraine headaches.*

Comment: Thank you for this little gem, it works perfectly!!!  It's also reassurring to know that I was barking up the right tree when I was trying to assign it to a string and replace the double quotation marks.  

This is certainly an effective migraine relief :)  

Many thanks for taking the time to look at this.